# Android OutputStream ByteArray changes oddly

Tags: android, sockets, arrays, outputstream

I writed a little Andoid application to control my self-made tank. The code is pretty much a direct translation from my C# powered controller client which is working fine. Problem is that when I run the Android version on an emulator everything is working just as should, but when I try it with my phone the ByteArray what I'm sending starts making odd behaviors.

**Examples:**

```
ByteArrays sent from an emulator:
11: 008|0|000|0
11: 022|0|000|0
11: 034|0|000|0
11: 043|0|000|0
11: 049|0|000|0
11: 052|0|000|0
11: 054|0|000|0
11: 052|0|000|0
11: 040|0|000|0
11: 034|0|000|0
11: 025|0|000|0
11: 016|0|000|0
11: 009|0|000|0
11: 003|1|000|0
11: 012|1|000|0
11: 027|1|000|0
11: 036|1|000|0
11: 043|1|000|0
11: 057|1|000|0
11: 063|1|000|0
11: 067|1|000|0
11: 068|1|000|0
11: 063|1|000|0
11: 048|1|000|0
```

```
ByteArrays sent from a phone:
11: 000|0|008|0
11: 000|0|007|0
12: 000|0|006|00
10: 00|0|005|0
12: 000|0|003|00
10: 00|0|001|0
12: 000|0|003|10
12: 00|0|005|100
9: 0|0|007|1
12: 000|0|009|10
12: 00|0|010|100
9: 0|0|012|1
12: 000|0|014|10
12: 00|0|016|100
9: 0|0|018|1
12: 000|0|020|10
12: 00|0|022|100
9: 0|0|024|1
12: 000|0|026|10
12: 00|0|027|100
9: 0|0|029|1
12: 000|0|030|10
12: 00|0|031|100
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private VerticalSeekBar leftBar;
private VerticalSeekBar rightBar;
private TCPClient mTcpClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leftBar = (VerticalSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.leftSeekBar);
    leftBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar v, int integer, boolean tosi) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax() / 2);
            leftBar.updateThumb();
        }
    });

    rightBar = (VerticalSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.rightSeekBar);
    rightBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar v, int integer, boolean tosi) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax() / 2);
            rightBar.updateThumb();
        }
    });
}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(leftBar, rightBar);
        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new connectTask().execute();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mTcpClient != null) mTcpClient.stopClient();
}
}
```

**TCPClient.java:**

```
public class TCPClient {
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.2";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 65535;
private boolean mRun = false;
private VerticalSeekBar leftBar;
private VerticalSeekBar rightBar;

public TCPClient(VerticalSeekBar leftBar, VerticalSeekBar rightBar) {
    this.leftBar = leftBar;
    this.rightBar = rightBar;
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

public void run(){
    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();

        long lastSend = System.nanoTime();
        byte[] sendBytes;
        int motor1;
        int motor2;
        int motor1send = 0;
        int motor2send = 0;
        int rev1;
        int rev2;

        while (mRun) {
            try {
                motor1 = leftBar.getProgress() - 100;
                motor2 = rightBar.getProgress() - 100;

                if(motor1 < 0){
                    motor1 = motor1 * -1;
                    rev1 = 1;
                } else
                    rev1 = 0;

                if(motor2 < 0){
                    motor2 = motor2 * -1;
                    rev2 = 1;
                } else
                    rev2 = 0;

                if(motor1 != motor1send || motor2 != motor2send || (System.nanoTime() - lastSend) / 1000000 > 500) {
                    motor1send = motor1;
                    motor2send = motor2;

                    sendBytes = (String.format("%03d", motor1) + "|" + rev1 + "|" + String.format("%03d", motor2) + "|" + rev2).getBytes();

                    stream.write(sendBytes);
                    stream.flush();

                    lastSend = System.nanoTime();
                }
            } catch(Exception ignored) {}
            if (!mRun) break;
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
}
```

I have tried a pretty much everything I know for five hours without any success. I'm totally out of ideas what to do or where the problem is.

Comment: is `leftBar` a View? we can not access View at background thread. please get the progress value in main thread(UI thread) and post it to your background thread to send to server.

Comment: `11: 052|0|000|0`  ??? Is that from a byte array? How should i read that? Post the bytes in hex notation please.

Comment: `what I'm sending starts making odd behaviors.`. I would think that what you would receive was different.

Comment: I  see no code where you print the sendBytes string. Explain where the `11:` comes from.

Comment: `String.format("%03d"`. It is strange that that sometimes results in less then three digits. But then i still dont know how you log/print that string. You are not sending bytes. You are sending a string.

Comment: You print/log on the receiving side.`12: 000|0|006|00
10: 00|0|005|0`. The `0` you have too much on one line is missing on the next.

Comment: All is caused by not having a message separator.

Comment: @greenapps That's the ByteArray converted back to string. The first number is the amount of bytes received. I noticed too that the lines are combining with each others. How can I prevent this for happening?

Comment: @greenapps I can't find anything useful information on google about separating those messages. Can you give a code snippet or something?

Comment: Make lines from your strings. So add a "\n" at the end. Now the server should read lines. The \n is the newline character and for your protocol the message separator.

Comment: `That's the ByteArray converted back to string`. Nonsense. You just format a string from some values.